# Reading power specifications

Tags: power

If a label says 100-240V AC @ 1A do we assume that the 1A is for 100v or 240v ?

Assuming it's 1A at 100v is equivalent to around 0.41A at 240V.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assume that it's 1A *across the entire range*. Thinking that it's lower at higher voltages is bad engineering.

Answer (score 0):

It operates between 100 to 240VAC and it can draw a maximum of 1A before something bad happens. To draw current means whatever Ohm's Law tells you at the load. So if you have 100 VAC generated and 100 Ohms at the load, you have drawn 1A and having a lower resistance while keeping the voltage the same would really mess up the circuit.